# Socket.emit not working as intended

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am attempting to use node.js to create a login script. The user enters their information on a page and they are redirected to a validation page. The server than checks against a users database and confirms all the login info is matching.

The server then takes the client's socket and emits in this code:

```
    function emitverified(dbuser) {
    console.log(dbuser);
    io.to(dbuser).emit('l');
}
```

The client handles this in this code

```
socket.on('l', function () {
            console.log("Validation occurred successfully");
        });
```

At this time, the client is not receiving the l signal that is emitted.

Answer (score 1):

`.to` broadcast to a `room`. Join your client `socket` to `dbuser` first.

```
socket.join(dbuser);
server.to(dbuser).emit('l');
```